# Winterdom BizTalk Pipeline Test

Tags: unit-testing, biztalk

I'm using the great Winterdom BizTalk test library to try to test the debatching of a flat file into 15 records.

The receive pipeline is working great when deployed to BizTalk.

Here's my unit test:

```
[DeploymentItem(@"TestData\Maps\FromCarrier\UPSSampleUpdate.csv")]
    [TestMethod]
    public void UPSTrackTrace_DebatchAndConvertUPSUpdateFFToXml()
    {

        FFDisassembler ff = Disassembler.FlatFile().WithHeaderSpec<Vasanta.Int.Carrier.Schemas.Carriers.UPS.TrackAndTrace.TandTHeader>();
        ff.WithDocumentSpec<Vasanta.Int.Carrier.Schemas.Carriers.UPS.TrackAndTrace.TandTBody>();

        ReceivePipelineWrapper pipeline = Pipelines.Receive().WithDisassembler(ff);

        // Create the input message to pass through the pipeline
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream("UPSSampleUpdate.csv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
            file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
        }

        IBaseMessage inputMessage = MessageHelper.CreateFromStream(stream);

        MessageCollection output = pipeline.Execute(inputMessage);

        Assert.AreEqual(15, output.Count);

    }
```

Running the test raises the following error:
Test method

```
Vasanta.Int.Carrier.UnitTests.Pipelines.FromCarrier.UPSUpdateFFDisassemble.UPSTrackTrace_DebatchAndConvertUPSUpdateFFToXml threw exception: 
System.Xml.XmlException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.


And this stack trace:
Microsoft.BizTalk.ParsingEngine.UngetBuffer.Push(String str, Int32 index, Int32 howMany)
Microsoft.BizTalk.ParsingEngine.DataReader.Unget(String str, Int32 index, Int32 count)
Microsoft.BizTalk.ParsingEngine.FFScanner.MatchDelimited()
Microsoft.BizTalk.ParsingEngine.FFScanner.Match()
Microsoft.BizTalk.ParsingEngine.FFScanner.InternalRead()
Microsoft.BizTalk.ParsingEngine.BufferedTokenReader.Read()
Microsoft.BizTalk.ParsingEngine.FFScanner.Read()
Microsoft.BizTalk.ParsingEngine.Parser.Scan()
Microsoft.BizTalk.ParsingEngine.Parser.Resume()
Microsoft.BizTalk.ParsingEngine.Parser.Parse()
Microsoft.BizTalk.ParsingEngine.FFReader.State.InitialState.Read(FFReader reader)
Microsoft.BizTalk.ParsingEngine.FFReader.State.InitialState.Read(FFReader reader)
Microsoft.BizTalk.ParsingEngine.FFReader.Read()
Microsoft.BizTalk.Streaming.XmlTranslatorStream.ProcessXmlNodes(Int32 count)
Microsoft.BizTalk.Streaming.XmlBufferedReaderStream.ReadInternal(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
Microsoft.BizTalk.Streaming.EventingReadStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
Microsoft.BizTalk.Streaming.MarkableForwardOnlyEventingReadStream.ReadInternal(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
Microsoft.BizTalk.Streaming.EventingReadStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer(Char[] userBuffer, Int32 userOffset, Int32 desiredChars, Boolean& readToUserBuffer)
System.IO.StreamReader.Read(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InitTextReaderInput(String baseUriStr, Uri baseUri, TextReader input)
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String url, TextReader input, XmlNameTable nt)
System.Xml.XmlTextReader..ctor(TextReader input)
Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.XmlDasmReader.GetReader(Boolean bValidate, Stream data, Encoding encoding, SchemaList envelopeSpecNames, SchemaList documentSpecNames)
Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.XmlDasmReader..ctor(IPipelineContext pipelineContext, IBaseMessageContext msgctx, Stream data, Encoding encoding, Boolean saveEnvelopes, XPathAnnotationCollection xac, NodeProcessor defaultProcessor, Boolean allowUnrecognizedMessage, Boolean validateDocument, SchemaList envelopeSpecNames, SchemaList documentSpecNames, MsgTypeSchema schemaList, Boolean promoteProperties, Boolean bamTracking, SuspendCurrentMessageFunction documentScanner)
Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.XmlDasmReader.CreateReader(IPipelineContext pipelineContext, IBaseMessageContext messageContext, MarkableForwardOnlyEventingReadStream data, Encoding encoding, Boolean saveEnvelopes, Boolean allowUnrecognizedMessage, Boolean validateDocument, SchemaList envelopeSpecNames, SchemaList documentSpecNames, IFFDocumentSpec docSpecType, SuspendCurrentMessageFunction documentScanner)
Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.FFDasmComp.Disassemble2(IPipelineContext pc, IBaseMessage inMsg)
Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.FFDasmComp.Disassemble(IPipelineContext pc, IBaseMessage inMsg)
Microsoft.Test.BizTalk.PipelineObjects.Stage.Execute(IPipelineContext pipelineContext, IBaseMessage inputMessage)
Microsoft.Test.BizTalk.PipelineObjects.GenericPipeline.ExecuteSubPipeline(IPipelineContext pipelineContext, IBaseMessage inputMessage, Int32 startStageIndex, Int32 endStageIndex)
Microsoft.Test.BizTalk.PipelineObjects.ReceivePipeline.Execute(IPipelineContext pipelineContext)
Winterdom.BizTalk.PipelineTesting.ReceivePipelineWrapper.Execute(IBaseMessage inputMessage)
x.Int.Carrier.UnitTests.Pipelines.FromCarrier.UPSUpdateFFDisassemble.UPSTrackTrace_DebatchAndConvertUPSUpdateFFToXml() in C:\Development\x.Int.Carrier\Dev\V1.0\Src\Solutions\Carrier\x.Int.Carrier.UnitTests\Pipelines\FromCarrier\UPSUpdateFFDisassemble.cs: line 59
```

Can anyone see where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not you.  There are a number of 'things' that exist in the BizTalk runtime that are not recreated by any of the Pipeline Test tools.

You best option is to download the source code and run it within Visual Studio to see where it breaks.

Side comment: I run all my tests within BizTalk.